# Arbitrary transformation of a 1D function into another

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 1D function (a spectrum in fact, n points representing amplitude vs. wavelength, call it sp1). This spectrum changes shape into another spectrum (sp2) as a function of experimental manipulation:
[image: spectrum plot]

My question: how can I determine the transformation matrix that transforms sp1 into sp2? Is this even a linear transformation that can be represented by a matrix transformation? If not, what type of transformation would I need?

My 2nd question: once I know the above, how can I modify the transformation by a single scalar (call it a) that varies from 0.0 to 1.0, that will gradually and continuously transform sp1 into sp2, such that when a=0.0 the result is exactly sp1, when a=1.0 the result is sp2 and when a is in-between I get a spectrum whose shape is intermediate between the two?

Any tips greatly appreciated.
Many thanks,
Peter Stys

Comment: I don't see how a matrix enters into this. But for any two real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ on a space $X$ (here, take $X$ to be your values of "nm", so probably a subset of the reals), the real-valued function $F:I\times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $F(t,x)=(1-t)f(x) + tg(x)$ on $X$ (for $t\in I=[0,1]$) has the property that $F(0,x)=f(x)$ and $F(1,x)=g(x)$. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then so is $F$, and thus so is $F_t:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ for each $t\in I$, where $F_t(x)=F(t,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, zou want to map a vector A (sp1) onto a vector B (sp2). Take your measurements as a vector. One possible solution to do so is to write it as a equation like:
$\vec{B} = C \vec{A}$
$C$ will only contain diagonal elements. The i-th diagonal element will be $\frac{B_i}{A_i}$.
For your second problem, you can calculate the differenze of the two vectors $\vec{A} - \vec{B}$ and add this difference scaled by your scalar $a$ to $B$ and get any intermediate position:
$\vec{C}_{intermediate} = a \cdot (\vec{A} - \vec{B}) + \vec{B}$
Hope that helps.

> > Thanks, this is useful, however things break down when there is a translation (which is common) such as:
> >     [image]

(so that Ai will be 0 or very small) or even when sp1 decays to very low values making errors excessive when one simply scales vertically. I was looking for a general transformation that would handle scaling/shape change/translation regardless of how sp1 and sp2 are related.
P.